# JSON & PHP data retrieval of Selected Fields or Parameters (Names)

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json

I have made a json request which works fine, but it is showing whole 'json data' as sent from php file. I need only the names of the people. Can someone help me out ?

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#but1').click(function(){
        $.ajax({
            url: "http://localhost/task6/callback.php",
            method: "POST",
            data:{format:"json"},
            type: 'GET',
            success: function(response) {
                alert("hi");
                var alpha =JSON.parse(response);
                $('div').html(alpha);
            }
        });
    });
});
</script> 
</head>
<body> 
<button id=but1>Button</button> 
<div>
Jack
</div> 
</body> 
</html>
```

PHP File:

```
<?php 
$arr = '{"List":[{"name": "Maria"},{"name":"Albert"},{"name":"Joseph"}]}';
echo json_encode($arr);
?>
```

Output:

```
{"List":[{"name": "seema"},{"name":"Albert"},{"name":"Sita"}]}
```

Can someone help me get only the names of these 3 people, instead of this whole string ? *(I have removed "+" signs as per comments)*

ANSWER : **@ THNX Codefox**. It worked following changes I made:

**Ajax Callback:**

```
success: function(response) {
alert("hi");
var alpha =JSON.parse(response);
$.each(alpha, function(index,value){
$('div').append(alpha[index].name);
}); 
}
```

**Json string in PHP:**

```
$arr = '[{"name": "Maria"},{"name":"Albert"},{"name":"Joseph"}]';
```

Comment: why there are + signs???

Comment: Removed the signs, but still I need the 3 names of the people, instead of whole list.

Comment: WHY dont people take the time to learn any more, as it will save them time in the future.. Learn the basics and that way you wont have to wait for people to solve common concepts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all change your Code in the php file remove the `+` form the json String. It shouldn't be there.

JSON should look like this in my opinion:

```
[{"name": "seema"},{"name": "Albert"},{"name": "Sita"}]
```

Second change you can do is:

```
$('#but1').click(function(){
        $.ajax({
            url: "http://localhost/task6/callback.php",
            method: "POST",
            data:{format:"json"},
            dataType: "json",
            type: 'GET',
            success: function(response) {
                alert("hi");
                $('div').html(response[0].name);
            }
        });
    });
```

Comment: I did both things, but I am not getting anything on screen now. Console.log  shows error "Cannot read property '0' of undefined"

Comment: Edited the post, this should work. Otherwise set header('Content-Type: application/json'); in your php file

Comment: Yes, it did. I have added the changes I made to make it Run!

Answer (score 0):

1 - I don't think "+" is valid JSON string.

2 - Once you have valid JSON you can do this:

```
var alpha =JSON.parse(response);
var names = [];
alpha.List.forEach(function(element) {
  names.push(element.name);
});
```

Another way:

```
var names = alpha.List.map(function(e){
  return e.name;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to put the "dataType" parameter:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#but1').click(function(){
        $.ajax({
            url: "http://localhost/task6/callback.php",
            method: "POST",
            data:{format:"json"},
            dataType:"json",
            type: 'GET',
            success: function(response) {
                console.log('JSON object',response);
                $('div').html(alpha);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

And..in your PHP file..you don't need to encode..a JSON that already has been encoded.

Just echo your JSON.

Or, pass an array to json_encode..then, you will have a "fresh" JSON.

Example:

```
<?php
$myData = ["name"=>"Eduardo","github"=>"http://github.com/eduardostuart"];
header('Content-type:application/json');
echo json_encode($myData);
die;
```

Answer (score 0):

first decode your string, Check the following code its working for me..

```
$arr = '{"List":[{"name": "Maria"},{"name":"Albert"},{"name":"Joseph"}]}';
$res=json_decode($arr);
$data=array();
$data=$res->List;
for($i=0;$i<sizeof($data);$i++)
{
    echo $data[$i]->name;
}
```